# Leading whitespace removed in plain text emails

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365

I'm using Microsoft's Exchange Web Services to send a Plain text email.
I'm setting the `Body` property of the `EmailMessage` and then setting the `Body`'s `BodyType` to `BodyType.PlainText`.

When I have leading whitespace in the text this gets removed in the email saved in the Sent Items folder and in the received email at the other end.

I've verified that the leading whitespace is still there when I set the `Body` property of the message.

Is there a way to preserve the leading whitespace in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a non-breaking space (0xA0) instead of the simple space (0x20)?